# Find out IMAP and SMTP settings for an email address

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, imap, smtp

I have an email address `myname@company.com`. I currently access my emails through a browser at `mail.company.com`, which uses the Outlook web app. I would like to be able to access them through other programs such as Thunderbird, however to do this I need to do know the IMAP and SMTP servers. If (in the Outlook web app) I go to `Options>Settings for POP or IMAP access` then under all three settings (POP, IMAP and SMTP) it says "Not available". Is there any other way of determining the settings? I tried sending myself an email from it and analysing the header but couldn't see anything of any use in there.

Comment: If this email address belongs to the company that employs you, and you are not in the IT or ownership of this company, this is not the place you should be asking this question. Please contact your company IT or technical staff for questions like this.

Comment: If you don't know what the configuration should be, based on the information you provided, we can't tell you.  Contact your IT Administrator